# Schedule task to run once daily at specific time | Celery

Tags: python, celery, config, celerybeat

I want to schedule running two tasks at 16h UTC **once per day.**

To do so, I've implemented this celery config:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab


CELERY_IMPORTS = ('api.tasks')
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 30
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'book-task': {
        'task': 'api.tasks.get_data',
        # At 16h UTC everyday
        'schedule': crontab(hour=16),
        'args': ({'book'}),
    },
    'pencils-task': {
        'task': 'api.tasks.get_data',
        # At 16h UTC everyday
        'schedule': crontab(hour=16),
        'args': ({'pencil'}),
    }
}
```

I run `celery worker -A app.celery --loglevel=info --pool=solo`  to run the celery worker after running `celery beat -A app.celery`  to launch celery beat.

With the config above, I have my two tasks running every minute starting 16h UTC. What is wrong with my config and how to fix ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify `minute` in your `crontab`, not passing `minute` means [the default value `*` is used](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.schedules.html#celery.schedules.crontab) which runs the job every minute.

Pass `minute=0` to run at the start of the hour

```
from celery.schedules import crontab


CELERY_IMPORTS = ('api.tasks')
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 30
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'book-task': {
        'task': 'api.tasks.get_data',
        # At 16h UTC everyday
        'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=16),
        'args': ({'book'}),
    },
    'pencils-task': {
        'task': 'api.tasks.get_data',
        # At 16h UTC everyday
        'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=16),
        'args': ({'pencil'}),
    }
}
```